# How to set volume for AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm trying to set volume for the AVPlayer but it doesn't seem to work. It takes system volume and ignores the value set in the code. Following is my code. How do we set a volume level?

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(string:recordingFileURL)!)
let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerController.player = player
playerController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity(rawValue: AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill.rawValue)

self.present(playerController, animated: true) {
    player.play()
    player.volume = 0.8 // Doesn't have any affect
}
```

Comment: My assumption was that the value set in above code should overwrite the system volume's value. Let's say system volume is 0.2 and my code above is setting it to 0.8, when player plays it should take 0.8 volume (set in code) and not 0.2 (system volume). Or may be I'm missing something? All I want to do is to give player a higher volume value irrespective of user's system volume level.

Comment: Well, your assumption was wrong. You cannot "overwrite the system volume's value". Think about it. The user has deliberately turned down the sound, and you think you're allowed to blast out sound anyway? That would be atrocious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1390127-volume) says this isn't possible.

> This property is used to control the player audio volume relative to the system volume. There is no programmatic way to control the system volume in iOS, but you can use the MediaPlayer framework’s MPVolumeView class to present a standard user interface for controlling system volume.

Since the AVPlayer volume is relative to the system volume, you can never force AVPlayer to play louder than the system volume.

Answer (score 5):

You said in a comment:

> My assumption was that the value set in above code should overwrite the system volume's value

That assumption is wrong. If the system volume is 0.2 and you set the player's volume to 0.8, all you're doing is making the player even softer (0.16). As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer/1390127-volume) tells you:

> This property is used to control the player audio volume relative to the system volume. There is no programmatic way to control the system volume in iOS.

Answer (score 5):

***player.volume = 0.8***

This property is most useful on iOS to control the volume of the AVSampleBufferAudioRenderer relative to other audio output, not for setting absolute volume.

Answer (score 0):

after giving player.volume = 100 it made an effect

Comment: Apple Docs say: "A value of 0.0 indicates silence; a value of 1.0 (the default) indicates full audio volume for the player instance."